# Layout and (nested?) DataTables in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, layout, datatable, primefaces

I am trying to dispose a `p:dataTable` beside a `p:button`. They need to lay in a `p:tab` that is contained in a `p:tabView`. The tabView is contained in the central `p:layoutUnit` of a `p:layout`.

I also need to put the dataTable inside a form for producing an ajax update of another component.

Before trying to add the button on the left of table, everything was fine:

```
<p:layout ...
    <p:layoutUnit ....
        <p:tabView ....
            <p:tab ....
                <h:form ....
                    <p:dataTable .....
```

But when adding an outer `h:dataTable` just out of the `h:form`, the tabView appears empty. If I try to use an outer `p:dataTable`, only one table is displayed without items.

Are there any limitations in putting a dataTable into another dataTable? If yes, are there other ways to reach this goal?

---

UPDATE

I have found that the right way is to use nested Layouts, a feature available since Primefaces 3.0 which is not yet fully documented.
Here is the [link to the feature request](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=867) and links to the showcase-lab.

Comment: Instead of "outer" I think you mean "inner"?

Comment: @MikeBraun: Currently there is only one table in my tab. Table has data inside, obviously. What I want is to have something other beside this table. Hope it's clearer...

Comment: @MikeBraun: I mean outer, indedd. The existing table would be inside the new outer table responsible for the new layout